# Asterisk PIAF dimensioning hardware

Tags: linux, hardware, asterisk, telecommunication, freepbx

I am looking for Suggested Hardware to install FIAF(asterisk) AWS EC2 instance. Enterprise grade Hardware to serve medium and large Enterprise IT industry.

```
OS: Centos    
Codec: G.711 alaw/ulaw
Maximum concurrent call: 500
Total SIP Peers: 1000
Only extension to extension calling. Not using to call via trunk like SIP or E1/T1.
```

I am seeking for the reply from the expert comunity!!

Answer (score 1):

PIAF not able do 500 concurrent calls on EC2 on any node.

For example on c1.medium will be 50-80 calls.

500 concurrent call task is not task for asterisk. You should use kamailio/opensips or scale to multiple asterisk boxes.

Extension2extensions calling also have use some protocol(usually sip).

Considering question you asked very likly you need outsource project to team with asterisk experience.

Comment: Thanks, but for 500 calls how much asterisk server with which EC2 instance i should go.

Comment: 500 calls is setup for hi-perfomance hardware server, even on that it can be not reachable(will greatly depend of dialplan and optimization). On ec2 no way run it.

Comment: Appreciate your concerns. What about any other server like dedicated or google cowed servers. I am running 250 concurrent calls on Pinless application over SIP Trunk. Here in my application using pjsip based library, csipsimple android, siphone iOS. Extension to extension calling only.

Comment: Question like "how much power  need to get 500 calls" have no any sence. It will GREATLY depend of dialplan and module usage. 500 calls should not be placed on one server (any hardware) if you have such questions.